# Can we use Haunted themes on Ghost 3.0

Tags: ghost-blog

The site  https://www.hauntedthemes.com/ says haunted themes compatible with Ghost 2.0
We have installed and setup Ghost version of 3.0. Before purchasing those themes we want to make sure that we get all the features of theme on our newer version of ghost. So can we use haunted themes with Ghost 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they've updated [their site](https://www.hauntedthemes.com/):

> No more compatibility issues. Our themes will always be compatible with the latest version of Ghost.